# Facing error while deploying my react app to the git hub with vs code

Tags: reactjs, github, visual-studio-code, deployment, rpc

error: RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: CANCEL (err 8)
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the exact same error, while pushing my code on github. Then I went to github discussions.

Solution - The slow or incosistent internet connection may cause this problem, make sure you've steady and fast internet connection, or it'll give you -

> error: RPC failed; HTTP 400 curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 5 was not closed cleanly: > CANCEL (err 8)

> send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet

> fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly

> Everything up-to-date

the above errors.

If this method doesn't solve your problem :
Refer to this GitHub discussion page - [RPC failed error discussion page](https://github.com/orgs/Homebrew/discussions/4069)